# Oracle XMLDB: how should i refactor this query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-xml-db

I have this query. its just running endlessly without any error. is there anything i'm doing wrong?

```
  SELECT RECID, extract(XMLRECORD,'/row') as xmlrecord 
  FROM ACCOUNT
  WHERE extractvalue(XMLRECORD,'/row/c1') =  '1001768908';
```

Account table has two fields: RECID(VARCHAR2) AND XMLRECORD(XMLTYPE)

EDIT: Is there a better way i can get results? i want to select account info based on a supplied customer no which is stored @ node c1

HELP! THANKS!

Comment: The account table looks like this <row><c1></c1>......etc

Comment: The table `ACCOUNT` may be endless (read huge/large).

Comment: `XML` based Oracle functions are inherently slow. So, the answer is wait, or try something else like regular expressions (which could be slow as well).

Comment: wow...2 days.8 views.no answer.it seems knowledge of xmldb is so few out there!